# SIMBL Agent crashing frequently

Tags: macos, big-sur, simbl

I just replaced a MacBook Pro running High Sierra with a new MacBook Pro M1 running Big Sur, and migrated my applications and accounts using Migration Assistant.

I noticed this evening that `ReportCrash` is using quite a bit of CPU, sometimes as much as 25% in both my regular user account and my admin account. I opened Console and saw that there were lots of Crash Reports from SIMBL Agent -- every 20-30 minutes in my user account and even more frequently in the admin account.

I removed the directories `~/Library/Application Support/SIMBL` and `/Library/Application Support/SIMBL` (they both just contained `SafariSource.bundle`), but this didn't solve the problem.

Then I checked `system.log`, and every few seconds it's logging

```
Aug 29 00:11:05 Barry-Margolins-MacBook com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (net.culater.SIMBL.Agent[29138]): removing service since it exited with consistent failure - OS_REASON_OBJC | Objective-C garbage collection is no longer supported.
Aug 29 00:11:05 Barry-Margolins-MacBook com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (net.culater.SIMBL.Agent): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
```

I tried killing this launchd service with

```
sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchAgents/net.culater.SIMBL.Agent.plist
```

and got the error:

> /Library/LaunchAgents/net.culater.SIMBL.Agent.plist: Could not find specified service
> Unload failed: 113: Could not find specified service

What do I have to do to kill this?

Comment: What are you using SIMBL for? Also have you rebooted?

Comment: I have no idea what I'm using it for, it was probably for something I used many years ago.

Comment: I have a feeling it was for a Mail plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I removed the file

```
/Library/LaunchAgents/net.culater.SIMBL.Agent.plist
```

and rebooted, and this has stopped.